# Difference between function declaration and function expression in object literal

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have object literal with a method:

```
const testObj = {
   method: function() {
      console.log('declaration');
   } 
}
```

and the same object with metod defined in another way:

```
const testObj = {
   method() {
     console.log('declaration');
   }
}
```

What's exactly a difference between in defining method field in two above examples? I know about function hoisting and functions declarations can be used before they appear in code, but when defining function as object field it doesn't seems to matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no difference, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions
>   on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a
>   function assigned to the method's name.

Comment: I'd say that "starting with [version]" is actually a *huge* difference, in cases when compatibility with browsers pre-dating that version would utterly break at the new syntax.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol without any doubts, the second example will works only in environment that support ECMAScript 2015, but if consider environment that support ECMAScript 2015, both examples behaves in the same way

Answer (score 0):

There’s not a difference. The latter is just the shorthand syntax for writing the same thing.

For example, in CSS you can assign a different border radius to each corner individually: `border-top-radius: 5px`. The shorthand would be: `border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 10px`.

Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) page on MDN for more information on method functions.

Edit: Fixed typo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two. The one is just a shorthand for the other. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions
>   on objects initializers is introduced. **It is a shorthand for a
>   function assigned to the method's name.**

The documentation goes on to give this example:

> Given the following code:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>     foo: function() {
>         /* code */
>     },
>     bar: function() {
>         /* code */
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> You are now able to shorten this to:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>     foo() {
>         /* code */
>     },
>     bar() {
>         /* code */
>     }
> };
> ```